# solaris zfs pool import crash

Tags: solaris, zfs

I do run my nas on solaris 11.3. I had a system crash a few days ago. Reason unknown. Afterwards I wasn't able to import the pool anymore. I exported the pool already so that I can boot without a new crash. The pool isn't the rpool. But I do need the data. Otherwise 20 years of children growing are gone. I checked the backup but this stopped a few months ago due to space limits.
So status
    zpool import shows a healthy pool

```
root@solaris:~# zpool import
  pool: mediapool1
    id: 8470162457149274931
 state: ONLINE
status: The pool was last accessed by another system.
action: The pool can be imported using its name or numeric identifier and
        the '-f' flag.
   see: http://support.oracle.com/msg/ZFS-8000-EY
config:

        mediapool1                 ONLINE
          raidz1-0                 ONLINE
            c0t5000C500A2C3F5D9d0  ONLINE
            c0t5000C500A2C40ECEd0  ONLINE
            c0t5000C500A2C4122Bd0  ONLINE
```

but as soon as I do the `zpool import mediapool` I run into a kernel oops.
I exchanged the whole system. Sas controller, proz, mainboard, ram, Os (Solaris 11.4), powersupply. Nothing changed.

```
zdb -e -dddd

root@solaris:~# zdb -e -dddd mediapool1
Dataset mediapool1 [ZPL], ID 18, cr_txg 1, 224K, 10 objects, rootbp DVA[0]=<0:903a3a5c000:4000:RZM:3> [L0 DMU objset] fletcher4 lzjb LE unique unencrypted size=800L/200P birth=10836736L/10836736P fill=10 contiguous 3-copy cksum=1416247ffb:6ec9c299cf2:1423227024d05:28fa8c22fe2105

    Deadlist: 0 (0/0 comp)

        mintxg 0 -> obj 21

    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
         0    7    16K    16K  74.5K    16K   31.25  DMU dnode
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES
        dnode maxblkid: 0

    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
        -1    1    16K    512  10.5K    512  100.00  ZFS user/group used
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES
        dnode maxblkid: 0
        microzap: 512 bytes, 1 entries

                0 = 0xdf20

    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
        -2    1    16K    512  10.5K    512  100.00  ZFS user/group used
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES
        dnode maxblkid: 0
        microzap: 512 bytes, 1 entries

                0 = 0xdf20

    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
         1    1    16K    512  10.5K    512  100.00  ZFS master node
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES USERUSED_ACCOUNTED
        dnode maxblkid: 0
        microzap: 512 bytes, 7 entries

                ROOT = 0x4
                SA_ATTRS = 0x2
                casesensitivity = 0x2
                VERSION = 0x6
                DELETE_QUEUE = 0x3
                SHARES = 0x7
                normalization = 0

    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
         2    1    16K    512  10.5K    512  100.00  SA master node
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES USERUSED_ACCOUNTED
        dnode maxblkid: 0
        microzap: 512 bytes, 2 entries

                LAYOUTS = 0x6
                REGISTRY = 0x5

    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
         3    1    16K    512  10.5K    512  100.00  ZFS delete queue
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES USERUSED_ACCOUNTED
        dnode maxblkid: 0
        microzap: 512 bytes, 0 entries


    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
         4    1    16K    512  10.5K    512  100.00  ZFS directory
                                        168   bonus  System attributes
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES USERUSED_ACCOUNTED
        dnode maxblkid: 0
        path    /
        uid     0
        gid     0
        atime   Tue Jun 20 09:39:20 2017
        mtime   Sat Jun 17 14:02:19 2017
        ctime   Sat Jun 17 14:02:19 2017
        crtime  Wed Jun 14 08:43:52 2017
        gen     4
        mode    040755
        size    5
        parent  4
        links   5
        pflags  0x40800000344
        microzap: 512 bytes, 3 entries

                backup = 11 (type: Directory)
                fs_userhome = 10 (type: Directory)
                export = 12 (type: Directory)

    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
         5    1    16K  1.50K  10.5K  1.50K  100.00  SA attr registration
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES USERUSED_ACCOUNTED
        dnode maxblkid: 0
        microzap: 1536 bytes, 21 entries

                ZPL_ZNODE_ACL = 0x5803000f : [88:3:15]
                ZPL_RDEV = 0x800000a : [8:0:10]
                ZPL_LINKS = 0x8000008 : [8:0:8]
                ZPL_ATIME = 0x10000000 : [16:0:0]
                ZPL_GID = 0x800000d : [8:0:13]
                ZPL_PAD = 0x2000000e : [32:0:14]
                ZPL_SCANSTAMP = 0x20030012 : [32:3:18]
                ZPL_SIZE = 0x8000006 : [8:0:6]
                ZPL_UID = 0x800000c : [8:0:12]
                ZPL_CTIME = 0x10000002 : [16:0:2]
                ZPL_MAC_LABEL = 0x30014 : [0:3:20]
                ZPL_MTIME = 0x10000001 : [16:0:1]
                ZPL_MODE = 0x8000005 : [8:0:5]
                ZPL_FLAGS = 0x800000b : [8:0:11]
                ZPL_PARENT = 0x8000007 : [8:0:7]
                ZPL_DACL_ACES = 0x40013 : [0:4:19]
                ZPL_CRTIME = 0x10000003 : [16:0:3]
                ZPL_SYMLINK = 0x30011 : [0:3:17]
                ZPL_GEN = 0x8000004 : [8:0:4]
                ZPL_DACL_COUNT = 0x8000010 : [8:0:16]
                ZPL_XATTR = 0x8000009 : [8:0:9]

    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
         6    1    16K    16K  21.5K    32K  100.00  SA attr layouts
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES USERUSED_ACCOUNTED
        dnode maxblkid: 1
        Fat ZAP stats:
                Pointer table:
                        1024 elements
                        zt_blk: 0
                        zt_numblks: 0
                        zt_shift: 10
                        zt_blks_copied: 0
                        zt_nextblk: 0
                ZAP entries: 1
                Leaf blocks: 1
                Total blocks: 2
                zap_block_type: 0x8000000000000001
                zap_magic: 0x2f52ab2ab
                zap_salt: 0x32d772cd
                Leafs with 2^n pointers:
                        9:      1 *
                Blocks with n*5 entries:
                        0:      1 *
                Blocks n/10 full:
                        1:      1 *
                Entries with n chunks:
                        4:      1 *
                Buckets with n entries:
                        0:    511 ****************************************
                        1:      1 *

                2 = [ 5  6  4  12  13  7  11  0  1  2  3  8  16  19 ]

    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
         7    1    16K    512  10.5K    512  100.00  ZFS directory
                                        168   bonus  System attributes
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES USERUSED_ACCOUNTED
        dnode maxblkid: 0
        path    /.zfs/shares
        uid     0
        gid     0
        atime   Wed Jun 14 08:43:53 2017
        mtime   Wed Jun 14 08:43:52 2017
        ctime   Wed Jun 14 08:43:52 2017
        crtime  Wed Jun 14 08:43:52 2017
        gen     4
        mode    040555
        size    2
        parent  7
        links   2
        pflags  0x40800000344
        microzap: 512 bytes, 0 entries


    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
        10    1    16K    512  10.5K    512  100.00  ZFS directory
                                        168   bonus  System attributes
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES USERUSED_ACCOUNTED
        dnode maxblkid: 0
        path    /fs_userhome
        uid     0
        gid     0
        atime   Fri Dec 21 06:21:30 2018
        mtime   Fri Jun 16 13:07:27 2017
        ctime   Fri Jun 16 13:07:27 2017
        crtime  Fri Jun 16 13:07:27 2017
        gen     20775
        mode    040755
        size    2
        parent  4
        links   2
        pflags  0x40800000344
        microzap: 512 bytes, 0 entries


    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
        11    1    16K    512  10.5K    512  100.00  ZFS directory
                                        168   bonus  System attributes
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES USERUSED_ACCOUNTED
        dnode maxblkid: 0
        path    /backup
        uid     0
        gid     0
        atime   Fri Dec 21 06:21:30 2018
        mtime   Sat Jun 17 13:47:04 2017
        ctime   Sat Jun 17 13:47:04 2017
        crtime  Sat Jun 17 13:47:04 2017
        gen     39220
        mode    040755
        size    2
        parent  4
        links   2
        pflags  0x40800000344
        microzap: 512 bytes, 0 entries


    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
        12    1    16K    512  10.5K    512  100.00  ZFS directory
                                        168   bonus  System attributes
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES USERUSED_ACCOUNTED
        dnode maxblkid: 0
        path    /export
        uid     0
        gid     0
        atime   Tue Jan 29 06:46:27 2019
        mtime   Sat Jun 17 14:02:19 2017
        ctime   Sat Jun 17 14:02:19 2017
        crtime  Sat Jun 17 14:02:19 2017
        gen     39413
        mode    040755
        size    2
        parent  4
        links   2
        pflags  0x40800000344
        microzap: 512 bytes, 0 entries

root@solaris:~# zdb -e -dddd mediapool1/export
Dataset mediapool1/export [ZPL], ID 879, cr_txg 37449, 202K, 8 objects, rootbp DVA[0]=<0:903a39cc000:4000:RZM:3> [L0 DMU objset] fletcher4 lzjb LE unique unencrypted size=800L/200P birth=10836735L/10836735P fill=8 contiguous 3-copy cksum=1695577b35:7cf5a5fbca5:16bf5de66c79d:2e4ab1d9943912

    Deadlist: 107K (9.00K/9.00K comp)

        mintxg 0 -> obj 217
        mintxg 1 -> obj 218
        mintxg 37455 -> obj 219

    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
         0    7    16K    16K  74.5K    16K   25.00  DMU dnode
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES
        dnode maxblkid: 0

    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
        -1    1    16K    512  10.5K    512  100.00  ZFS user/group used
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES
        dnode maxblkid: 0
        microzap: 512 bytes, 1 entries

                0 = 0x85e0

    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
        -2    1    16K    512  10.5K    512  100.00  ZFS user/group used
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES
        dnode maxblkid: 0
        microzap: 512 bytes, 1 entries

                0 = 0x85e0

    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
         1    1    16K     1K  10.5K     1K  100.00  ZFS master node
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES USERUSED_ACCOUNTED
        dnode maxblkid: 0
        microzap: 1024 bytes, 8 entries

                SA_ATTRS = 0x2
                DELETE_QUEUE = 0x3
                SHARES = 0x7
                casesensitivity = 0x2
                normalization = 0
                VERSION = 0x5
                utf8only = 0
                ROOT = 0x4

    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
         2    1    16K    512  10.5K    512  100.00  SA master node
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES USERUSED_ACCOUNTED
        dnode maxblkid: 0
        microzap: 512 bytes, 2 entries

                REGISTRY = 0x5
                LAYOUTS = 0x6

    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
         3    1    16K    512  10.5K    512  100.00  ZFS delete queue
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES USERUSED_ACCOUNTED
        dnode maxblkid: 0
        microzap: 512 bytes, 0 entries


    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
         4    1    16K    512  10.5K    512  100.00  ZFS directory
                                        168   bonus  System attributes
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES USERUSED_ACCOUNTED
        dnode maxblkid: 0
        path    /
        uid     0
        gid     0
        atime   Tue Jan 29 06:46:27 2019
        mtime   Wed May 20 16:50:07 2015
        ctime   Wed May 20 16:50:07 2015
        crtime  Wed Mar 13 21:27:28 2013
        gen     65199
        mode    040755
        size    3
        parent  4
        links   3
        pflags  0x40800000344
        microzap: 512 bytes, 1 entries

                home = 8 (type: Directory)

    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
         5    1    16K  1.50K  10.5K  1.50K  100.00  SA attr registration
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES USERUSED_ACCOUNTED
        dnode maxblkid: 0
        microzap: 1536 bytes, 21 entries

                ZPL_GID = 0x800000d : [8:0:13]
                ZPL_DACL_ACES = 0x40013 : [0:4:19]
                ZPL_CRTIME = 0x10000003 : [16:0:3]
                ZPL_MAC_LABEL = 0x30014 : [0:3:20]
                ZPL_ATIME = 0x10000000 : [16:0:0]
                ZPL_SIZE = 0x8000006 : [8:0:6]
                ZPL_LINKS = 0x8000008 : [8:0:8]
                ZPL_PAD = 0x2000000e : [32:0:14]
                ZPL_PARENT = 0x8000007 : [8:0:7]
                ZPL_MODE = 0x8000005 : [8:0:5]
                ZPL_DACL_COUNT = 0x8000010 : [8:0:16]
                ZPL_SYMLINK = 0x30011 : [0:3:17]
                ZPL_XATTR = 0x8000009 : [8:0:9]
                ZPL_SCANSTAMP = 0x20030012 : [32:3:18]
                ZPL_UID = 0x800000c : [8:0:12]
                ZPL_GEN = 0x8000004 : [8:0:4]
                ZPL_RDEV = 0x800000a : [8:0:10]
                ZPL_FLAGS = 0x800000b : [8:0:11]
                ZPL_ZNODE_ACL = 0x5803000f : [88:3:15]
                ZPL_CTIME = 0x10000002 : [16:0:2]
                ZPL_MTIME = 0x10000001 : [16:0:1]

    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
         6    1    16K    16K  21.5K    32K  100.00  SA attr layouts
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES USERUSED_ACCOUNTED
        dnode maxblkid: 1
        Fat ZAP stats:
                Pointer table:
                        1024 elements
                        zt_blk: 0
                        zt_numblks: 0
                        zt_shift: 10
                        zt_blks_copied: 0
                        zt_nextblk: 0
                ZAP entries: 1
                Leaf blocks: 1
                Total blocks: 2
                zap_block_type: 0x8000000000000001
                zap_magic: 0x2f52ab2ab
                zap_salt: 0x751fd0cd
                Leafs with 2^n pointers:
                        9:      1 *
                Blocks with n*5 entries:
                        0:      1 *
                Blocks n/10 full:
                        1:      1 *
                Entries with n chunks:
                        4:      1 *
                Buckets with n entries:
                        0:    511 ****************************************
                        1:      1 *

                2 = [ 5  6  4  12  13  7  11  0  1  2  3  8  16  19 ]

    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
         7    1    16K    512  10.5K    512  100.00  ZFS directory
                                        168   bonus  System attributes
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES USERUSED_ACCOUNTED
        dnode maxblkid: 0
        path    /.zfs/shares
        uid     0
        gid     0
        atime   Wed Mar  4 06:30:06 2015
        mtime   Wed Mar 13 21:27:28 2013
        ctime   Wed Mar 13 21:27:28 2013
        crtime  Wed Mar 13 21:27:28 2013
        gen     65199
        mode    040555
        size    2
        parent  7
        links   2
        pflags  0x40800000344
        microzap: 512 bytes, 0 entries


    Object  lvl   iblk   dblk  dsize  lsize   %full  type
         8    1    16K    512  10.5K    512  100.00  ZFS directory
                                        168   bonus  System attributes
        dnode flags: USED_BYTES USERUSED_ACCOUNTED
        dnode maxblkid: 0
        path    /home
        uid     0
        gid     0
        atime   Tue Jan 29 06:46:27 2019
        mtime   Wed Mar 13 21:27:32 2013
        ctime   Wed Mar 13 21:27:32 2013
        crtime  Wed Mar 13 21:27:32 2013
        gen     65206
        mode    040755
        size    2
        parent  4
        links   2
        pflags  0x40800000344
        microzap: 512 bytes, 0 entries


root@solaris:~#
```

from my understanding ZFS should have some backup data available.
How to import these backup ?

Comment: Can you post the kernel stack trace?  It should be in `/var/adm/messages`.

Comment: Solaris does this a bit different but I guess better than I do have 200MB Crashdump https://www.dropbox.com/s/bmayjyro40hr4ms/crashdump.tar.gz?dl=0

Comment: So I'm back for the weekend. Wasnt aware of this extra log..

Comment: thats the link https://www.dropbox.com/s/pts16vglnpmjpxh/var-adm-messages.txt?dl=0
last working task at the zpool was destroying snapshots

Comment: Have you upgraded version of OS? In the begginging of your question you write about Solaris 11.3, in the middle - about Solaris 11.4. Try to boot with your previous solaris version. Also avoid of using GA versions of 11.3 and 11.4, try OS versions from support repository with critical bug-fixes - 11.3.36.7.0 or 11.4.6.4.0.

Comment: I tried both versions.  11.3 and 11.4. But I hadnt upgraded inside the release. 
Let me see. I'll give it a try. BUt it looks like the space maps are broken. and the fixed versiones of the OS cant repair them ...